# How can I add ?1 at the end of all URLs on my website?

Tags: .htaccess

How can I add ?1 at the end of all URLs on my website using .htaccess?

My website is cached somewhere and I don't know how and where.

In order to show the non-cache version of the page, I need to add ?1 or ?somenumber

How can I add ?1 at the end of all URLs on my website using .htaccess, what rule is for it?

My current .htaccess code

```
<IfModule LiteSpeed> 
CacheEngine off 
LiteMage off 
</IfModule>

Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(files)($|/) - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Try to add `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?1 [L,R=301]` before </IfModule>

Comment: @Hölderlin
 It doesn't seem to work but thank you.

Comment: I tested the code RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?1 [L,R=301]`` in [this sandbox](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/) and the result is as [expected](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=956313e5-d1d8-43cc-9cb3-e597e65ea226).

Comment: It's not really going to do anything if you place the rule "before `</IfModule>`" (except for requests to the homepage or static assets). However, if the "website is cached somewhere", how is the initial request expected to reach the server in the first place? The only way to "break the cache" is to _manually_ append the "cache busting" query string on the initial request and in the HTML response (when the page is generated) append the query string to all relevant links/assets at that stage. Not something you can (reasonably) do in `.htaccess`, and certainly not with a redirect. @Hölderlin